Intersection of a set with a von Neumann algebra
Let $A$ and $B$ be von Neumann algebras. Denote $W^*(A\cup B)$ by the von Neumann algebra generated by $A\cup B$.
Suppose that there exists a set $C$ such that $C\cap A=\{0\}$ and $C\cap B=\{0\}   $. Can we conclude that $C\cap W^*(A\cup B)= \{0\} $?

Hint: take $C = \big( W^*(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cup B) \big) \cup { 0 }$.

This already fails in dimension 2: If you take
$$
A=\{(a,0):\ a\in\mathbb C\},\qquad B=\{(0,b):\ b\in\mathbb C\},\qquad C=\{(c,c):\ c\in\mathbb C\}, 
$$
Then $W^*(A\cup B)=\mathbb C^2$, $A\cap C=B\cap C=\{0\}$, and $C\cap W^*(A\cup B)=C$.
